# Google DNS not updating MX or SPF information from 1&1 IONOS-hosted domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

We made a change to one of our MX records on Saturday, August 17, and . the change propagated fairly quickly. When we run a DNS check against it, it appears that every nameserver worldwide has picked up the change except Google.

Dig result from 8.8.8.8, showing MX value `ms1.vaspace.org` as still current:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> mx vaspace.org @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29105
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;vaspace.org.           IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
vaspace.org.        1110    IN  MX  20 ms2.vaspace.org.
vaspace.org.        1110    IN  MX  10 ms1.vaspace.org.

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Aug 22 08:15:39 EDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 80
```

Dig result from Open DNS, showing the correct MX setup:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> mx vaspace.org @208.67.222.222
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54488
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;vaspace.org.           IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
vaspace.org.        3600    IN  MX  10 marsspaceport.mail.protection.office365.us.
vaspace.org.        3600    IN  MX  20 ms2.vaspace.org.
```

Dig on SOA record:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> -t SOA vaspace.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59511
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;vaspace.org.           IN  SOA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
vaspace.org.        21599   IN  SOA ns1017.ui-dns.de. hostmaster.1and1.com. 2017033106 28800 7200 604800 300

;; Query time: 17 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Aug 22 08:16:17 EDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 112
```

Google is also not picking up the SPF record we created at the time the MX record was changed. Because of this, we're still having to relay some e-mail through our old, on-premises mail servers, and our sites that use Google DNS on their networks are having difficulty logging into services like Skype. Beyond making the MX record change, was there something else we should have done? All we did was change the "points to" value in the record and add a new SPF record. The domain `vaspace.org` is hosted by 1&1 IONOS. Whatever's going on, it appears to be confined to Google.

Comment: You should see a deceasing TTL values when making repeat queries indicating how long (in seconds) until the cached value expires. Additionally https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/cache allows you to flush cached records from Google's public resolvers expediting DNS changes

Comment: It doesn't appear to be word-wide. Queries from my location provide the new results across the board. That's not to say it isn't Google's problem; 8.8.8.8 is an anycast address and there must be hundreds of endpoints that could be resolving queries.

Comment: @HBruijn: We did try flushing the cache via that site. We did it once yesterday and once today. No joy.

Comment: @SmallClanger: Is this a case where we just need to wait it out?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with a 1and1 IONOS domain starting on 8/21/2019.  I called them, they acknowledged the issue and said they are working on it.  They had no time frame for resolution.  Meanwhile, we are migrating DNS to AWS because this is about the 5th time 1and1 DNS has had issues for us.

**UPDATE from Google**

> The anycast name servers for Ionos (1&1) with names like
>   nsXXXX.ui-dns.TLD in one of their data centers in the Eastern US
>   (reached from Google's peering with them in the NYC area) appear to
>   have problems with zone transfers, and are serving stale data, and for
>   some domains where the SOA record expire setting (next to last number
>   in the SOA data) is low enough, they are failing to resolve, since the
>   name servers are returning REFUSED.
>
> This is causing stale data and resolution failure from Google Public
>   DNS clients in the east of both the US and Canada, and even in South
>   America, since for our resolvers in these areas, the NYC peering point
>   between Google (AS15169) and 1&1/Ionos (AS8560) is the nearest one,
>   and DNS queries passing through it are reaching the Ionos datacenter
>   with these problems.
>
> We will try to disable the peering connection in NYC, but the problem
>   here is with the Ionos name servers.

You can track the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139870676

Comment: We're close to that, ourselves. When we called them, they mentioned that they've had other cases like this opened recently. Not a good look!

Comment: We updated out TTL on the main domain at IONOS and it started working for us.  It might be coincidence since they're working on it at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same issue. Google DNS 8.8.8.8 is returning 2 years old results for 1and1 sites from North America locations.

Look at this link https://dnschecker.org/#A/r2support.jlssolutions.com you will see google returns an old ip.

or this link https://dnschecker.org/#A/sms.jlssolutions.com Google has nothing.

Comment: They appear to have resolved the issue. If you check those domain names now, Google DNS is now picking up the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

Google put this in its issue tracker and I also opened a ticket with IONOS. Between the two of them, the issue was resolved yesterday. See the answer from @sonicblis posted above. The problem was with the peer connection between IONOS and Google, and only affected the Eastern Seaboard and parts of South America.